# How to assign a gulp destination to a folder and their subFolders

Tags: html, .htaccess, gulp, internationalization, task

Src:

```
.htaccess
html/
 home.html
js/
css/
```

Public:

```
html/
  ar/
   home.html
  en/
   home.html
js/
css/
```

I wanna move the .htaccess file to each HTML dir `HTML/` and their subFolders `en/` and `ar/`

Public: ( What I need )

```
html/
  .htaccess
  ar/
   .htaccess
   home.html
  en/
   .htaccess
   home.html
js/
css/
```

> I'm using the [gulp-html-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-i18n) in order to split the HTML files into two different dir

So, How can I do the task above? It is a gulp plugin can handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You could simple make an array of all your directories and loop through it and move for each file

```
var dirs = ['html/ar', 'html/en', 'html/pt'],
    file = gulp.src('path/of/.htaccess');

gulp.task('move', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
        file = file.pipe(gulp.dest(dirs[i]));
    }
    return file;
});
```